# preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Could some one explain this to me i am not familiar with preg_match_all filters, this code works fine except it does not return a negative value if one of the latitudes and longitudes is negative.

```
if ( preg_match_all( "#<td>\s+-?(\d+\.\d+)\s+</td>#", $output, $coords ) ) {
    list( $lat, $long ) = $coords[1];
    echo "Latitude: $lat\nLongitude: $long\n";
}
```

output:
    `Latitude: 30.6963 Longitude: 71.6207`  (longitude is missing a '-')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `coords` variable depends on what is matched by the code inside the  parentheses. Moving the optional minus sign (`-?`) inside the  parentheses should do the trick:

```
if ( preg_match_all( "#<td>\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+</td>#", $output, $coords ) ) {
```

See the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php) for details about preg in php and [php.net/preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) for the details of `preg_match_all`.

Comment: can you refer me to a link where i can understand all the filters used in preg_match_all, ineed to learn this

Comment: @unknown (yahoo): Added a paragraph about documentation

Answer (score 1):

Your sign is not in the parenthesis. $coords[1] contains the part of the regex that matched the part between ( and ). The +- are before the parenthesis, though, thus they are not part of what is matched and returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `preg_match()` API, you can use [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com) - it's really cool

```
$p = "<td>\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+</td>"; // no delimiters :)

pattern($p)->match($output)->forEach(function (Match $match) {
    $match->text();

    // or
    $match->group(1)->text();
    // or check if it's matched
    $match->group(1)->matched();
});
```