# Explain what this PHP regular expression means (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex

What is pattern mean in PHP:

`'#^/abc/(?P<abc>[^/]++)$#si'; // please expand this pattern's meaning.`

and what are strings can match of this pattern with `preg_match_all`?

Comment: @remus that's awesome thing I dreamed for years, thank you VERY much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern `'#^/abc/(?P<abc>[^/]++)$#si';` broken down like so:

> ```
> /^\/abc\/(?P<abc>[^\/]++)$/si
>
> ^ assert position at start of the string
> \/ matches the character / literally
> abc matches the characters abc literally (case insensitive)
> \/ matches the character / literally
> (?P<abc>[^\/]++) Named capturing group abc
>     [^\/]++ match a single character not present in the list below
>         Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back [possessive]
>         \/ matches the character / literally
> $ assert position at end of the string
> s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
> i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
> ```

(Source: http://regex101.com/r/hS6qE3 -- make sure you escape your `/` on the site as it assumes `/` is the php delimiter. In your pattern example, `#` is the delimiter instead, which is then wrapped in quotes and the string terminator `;`. The actual expression is simply `^/abc/(?P<abc>[^/]++)$` with the single-line and case insensitive modifiers.)

*Note the use of two `++` signs as well, which [changes the behavior from greedy to possessive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers).*

An example of a string that will match:

```
/abc/somethingelsenotafrontslash
```

You can read a quick explanation about `preg_match_all` [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586534/1214800)